# Only in production, BitBlt() returns 0, but then so does `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`

Tags: iis, pinvoke, gdi

Using the following [`BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) P/Invoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, 
    int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, uint dwRop);
```

And the following calling code:

```
if (0 == BitBlt(hdc1, 0, 0, 856, 2246, hdc2, 0, 0, (uint)RasterOpMode.SRCCOPY))
{
    var lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    ...
}
```

I'm getting a result from `BitBlt()` of `0` but I'm also getting a `lastError` of `0`.

The documentation for the return value of `BitBlt` is:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

From managed code, of course, we call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`, right?  So endorses the community at the bottom of the MSDN documentation.  I've also tried defining `BitBlt()` to return `bool` instead and that behaves the same.

This same code is working fine on two independent developer's machines when debugging through the Visual Studio development web server but failing on the IIS server.  I'm doing remote debugging to verify the exact circumstances of the code and passed parameters and return values.

Why might `BitBlt` return `0` (indicating an error) while an immediately subsequent call to `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` also returns 0 (indicating no error)?

They're all 64-bit Windows 7/2008 machines.  We're running IIS in 32-bit mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) only reliably works if `[DllImport]` has `SetLastError = true`. Otherwise the last error retrieved may actually belong to some other API call that happened in between. The default for `SetLastError` is `false`, so you have to explicitly say:

```cs
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int BitBlt (...)
```

Comment: Damn it, I knew that one!  ... Thank you!

Comment: For others, the error code was 6 as I'd seen listed elsewhere online.  The fix was to run the handles through CreateCompatibleDC().  It would fail locally on full IIS but not the development webserver without it.